# I have upgraded to gradle 7.2, Now my project is caughting an error

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.pom
- https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.pom
- https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

Comment: Please add the build.gradle file , and are you sure you have `google()` in your repositories in build.gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can reach [google Maven](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.android.tools.build#com.android.tools.build:gradle) and if you can , make sure that you have `google()` in Reporsitories section in your build.gradle .

And the most important thing , is that there is no `7.2.1` version as you can see with the link .

Change the `7.2.1` to `7.0.3` should fix the issue .